# CSS Drop Down submenu won't hide

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, menubar, submenu

I am trying to get my submenu to appear when the cursor is on the menu item, and when you go to another menu option the new submenu replace the other one, but right now the first submenu selected stay on the screen, never dissapear, and when you go to another menu option the other subenu appear kind of under the first one... can somebody help me with that? thank you!

html:

```
     <div id="menu">
<div class="menu" id="menu1" onmouseover="affiche(this)"><a href="#.html">   MENU1 </a>
    <div class="sousmenu" id="sousmenu1" style="display:none" onmouseout="affiche(this)">
        <div><a href="#.html">SOUSMENU11</a></div>
        <div><a href="#.html">SOUSMENU12</a></div>
        <div><a href="#.html">SOUSMENU13</a></div>
        <div><a href="#.html">SOUSMENU14</a></div>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="menu" id="menu2" onmouseover="affiche(this)"><a href="#.html">MENU2</a>
    <div class="sousmenu" id="sousmenu2" style="display:none" onmouseout="affiche(this)">
        <div><a href="#.html">SOUSMENU21</a></div>
        <div><a href="#.html">SOUSMENU22</a></div>
        <div><a href="#.html">SOUSMENU23</a></div>
        <div><a href="#.html">SOUSMENU24</a></div>
        <div><a href="#.html">SOUSMENU25</a></div>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="menu" id="menu3" onmouseover="affiche(this)"><a href="#.html">MENU3</a>
    <div class="sousmenu" id="sousmenu3" style="display:none" onmouseout="affiche(this)">
        <div><a href="#.html">SOUSMENU31</a></div>
        <div><a href="#.html">SOUSMENU32</a></div>
        <div><a href="#.html">SOUSMENU33</a></div>
        <div><a href="#.html">SOUSMENU34</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="menu" id="menu4"><a href="#">MENU4</a></div>
<div class="menu" id="menu4"><a href="#">MENU5</a></div>
<div class="menu" id="menu5"><a href="#">MENU6</a></div>
<div class="menu" id="menu6"><a href="#">MENU7</a></div>
```

CSS:

```
    #menu{
margin:0px 0 0 9px;
background:#50626c;
color:#fff;
float:left;
display:inline;}
    #menu div{
width:234px;
text-align:center;}
     .menu{
position:relative;}
    #menu div a:link, #menu div a:visited, #menu div a:hover{
color:#fff;
font-family:arial,sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
text-decoration:none;
padding-top:7px;
height:28px;
display:block;}
    #menu div a:link, #menu div a:visited{
background:url(BG.jpg) no-repeat;}
    #menu div a:hover, #menu div a:active, #menu div a:focus{
background:#4172CB ;
text-decoration: underline;}
     .sousmenu{
position:absolute;
left:234px;
top:0;}
```

js

```
function affiche(obj){
    var id = obj.id;

    for(var i = 1; i <= 2; i++){
            document.getElementById('sousmenu'+i).style.display = "none";
    }

    if(document.getElementById('sous'+id)){
            document.getElementById('sous'+id).style.display = "block";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're setting them all with the for loop and it's ignoring the if statement afterwards. Try putting the if statement inside the for loop and add an else for the other elements to be displayed as none. Also, there's a way to do this with just CSS hovers and no javascript you might want to look into. The main nav on this site (About/Portfolio/Contact/Extras) does that does it that way, CSS only: http://www.visionspark.com

But here's how to adjust your code:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 2; i++){
    if(document.getElementById('sous'+id)){
        document.getElementById('sous'+id).style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('sousmenu'+i).style.display = "none";
    }
}
```